# Missing chapter numbering in pandoc

Tags: chapters, pandoc, markdown

## Setup

This question regards the following workflow: markdown file (input) -> pandoc -> PDF (output)

Pandoc version:

```
$ pandoc --version
pandoc 2.9.2.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.20, texmath 0.12.0.2, skylighting 0.8.5
```

## Problem description

Expected behavior: Every chapter in a PDF book gets a chapter number. At the start of the first chapter I get a "Chapter 1" text before the chapter's title.

Behavior I get: No chapter numbering.

## Minimum Working Example (MWE)

### metadata.yaml

```
---
papersize: a4
documentclass: book
top-level-division: chapter
number-sections: true
---
```

### book.md

```
% Book Title
  Book subtitle
%
% April 1, 2023

# Introduction

This should have been Chapter 1.

Lorem Ipsum. Hello world!

# Chapter problem

This is chapter 2. Why is there no Chapter Numbering?

## Section

There is no section numbering either.
```

### Command to replicate

I use the following command to generate the PDF:

```
pandoc --metadata-file=metadata.yaml book.md -o book.pdf
```

## Question

What am I doing wrong? I assumed that pandoc would automatically number each chapter, but it apparently does not. Is there a way to force pandoc to number each chapter?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the `--number-sections` option to `pandoc` like this:

```
pandoc --metadata-file=temp.yaml --number-sections temp.md -o temp.pdf
```

To experiment replace the target `temp.pdf` by `temp.tex` and use `--standalone`  then inspect the tex file for `secnumdepth`.

CAVEAT: I am with pandoc `2.18`.

EDIT: actually here is how to do it with yaml file:

```
---
papersize: a4
documentclass: book
top-level-division: chapter
numbersections: true
---
```

Watch out how the variable is named and used.

So basically, you only had a typo of using `number-sections` in place of `numbersections`... the latter is the yaml variable the former is for the `-number-sections` command line toggle.

Comment: I can confirm your suggestion using pandoc 3.1.1, i.e. the numbers-option was mising.

Comment: @MS-SPO thanks.  Actually I overlooked that there *is* a yaml variable. See my edit.

Comment: Interesting: "number-sections: true" from the TO did not work (i.e. requires -N on the command line), while your "numbersections: 5" does (i.e. works without -N on the command line). The Pandoc manual is not very clear about which one to use.

Comment: @MS-SPO my `5` was a mistake I thought it was possible to customize `secnumdepth` but on studying man page of `pandoc` better it looks as `numbersections` in yaml  file (or metadata) is an all-or-nothing toggle.

Comment: May be it is. I tried your yaml and it worked with the TO's call. Miracles do happen :)

Comment: Thank you! I used the manual's `number-sections: true` as a variable, but I did not read through it carefully enough to realize that the variable's proper name is `numbersections`